# not able to get result length from ms crm web api call output in js

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

Below is my code snippet. I am trying to fetch all the Referenced Entities from ManyToOne Relationship of Annotation entity. In the result, I am able to get the object but when I'm trying to get the length of it, its giving "undefined". Please provide your valuable suggestions on this and how can we assign the Referenced Entity to a variable from result.

OR
**is there any possibility to retrieve all the entities that are associated with Annotation entity, using Web API Call ( Dynamics 365).**

```js
function fetchIt()
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var webAPICall = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='annotation')?$select=LogicalName&$expand=ManyToOneRelationships($select=ReferencedEntity)";
    req.open("GET", webAPICall, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
    req.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (this.readyState === 4)
        {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 200) {
                
                var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
                alert("results.valuelength: " +results.value.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++)
                {
                    var referencedEntity = results.value[i]["ReferencedEntity"];
                }
            } else {
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems

1. You never send your request. You're missing `req.send()`
2. It won't be `results.value` it will be `results.ManyToOneRelationships`

Then it will work

Comment: Yes @jasonscript, you are right. So, I answered it with adding the missing things. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Missed a small thing there. Instead of value, to check the length, we need to use ManyToOneRelationships (`results.ManyToOneRelationships.length`). Thank You.

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var webAPICall = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='annotation')?$select=LogicalName&$expand=ManyToOneRelationships($select=ReferencedEntity)";
//alert(webAPICall);
req.open("GET", webAPICall, true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
req.onreadystatechange = function ()
{            
    if (this.readyState === 4)
    {                
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200)
        {                   
            var results = JSON.parse(this.response);                    
            alert("Results length: " + results.ManyToOneRelationships.length);                   
            for (var i = 0; i < results.ManyToOneRelationships.length; i++)
            {
                var referencedEntity = results.ManyToOneRelationships[i]["ReferencedEntity"];
            }
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```